# How to save each row to csv in dataframe AND name the file based on the the first column in each row

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have the following df, with the row 0 being the header:

teacher,grade,subject

black,a,english

grayson,b,math

yodd,a,science

What is the best way to use export_csv in python to save each row to a csv so that the files are named:

black.csv

grayson.csv

yodd.csv

Contents of black.csv will be:

teacher,grade,subject

black,a,english

Thanks in advance!

Updated Code:

```
df8['CaseNumber'] = df8['CaseNumber'].map(str)
df8.set_index('CaseNumber', inplace=True)
for Casenumber, data in df8.iterrows():
data.to_csv('c:\\users\\admin\\' + Casenumber + '.csv')'''
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done simply by using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
     # Preempt the issue of columns being numeric by marking dtype=str
df = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv', header=1, dtype=str) 
df.set_index('teacher', inplace=True)

for teacher, data in df.iterrows():
    data.to_csv(teacher + '.csv')
```

Edits:

```
df8.set_index('CaseNumber', inplace=True)
for Casenumber, data in df8.iterrows():
    # Use r and f strings to make your life easier:
    data.to_csv(rf'c:\users\admin\{Casenumber}.csv')
```

Comment: hmm its saying key error.  the dataframe doesn't have an index anymore

Comment: If row 0 is still the "header", even after reading it in correctly with `header=1`... then you can make it the real header with `df.columns = df.iloc[0]` and `df = df[1:]`

Comment: i think i have it working.  Its now all in one column.  how would i go about transposing it?

Comment: What is your code? Add it to the question body~

Comment: Hey BeRT2me, I added it to the question.

Comment: @Harry123 Okay, I see your code snip-it, and I addressed some parts of it in my answer. What exactly is all in one column? What does your current input, output, and desired output, look like?

Comment: I have 8 columns and they are all on separate rows in one column. column 1 are the headers and column 2 is the data. i need to transpose it so the headers are in row1 and the data follows in row 2-n

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)